# SQL - Using "Where In" for adjacent lists/columns

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I am trying to build a SQL query that will pull the results of a customer ID and Order Type, and Order Date based on a two lists that are input. The lists contain the customer ID and Order Type.

I want to set up my *WHERE IN* statement to match with both the Customer ID and the Order ID. So if Customer 1 used Order Type 5, it will pull Customer 1s latest purchase through Order Type 5.

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT
customer_id,
order_type_id,
order_date
FROM table
WHERE order_date > 2020-11-15
AND customer_id IN ({{LIST}})
AND order_type_id IN ({{LIST}})
```

How can I combine the two IN statements?

Answer (score 1):

Both Postgres and MySQL support *tuples*.  This allows you to express the query as:

```
SELECT customer_id, order_type_id, order_date
FROM table
WHERE order_date > 2020-11-15 AND
      (customer_id, order_type_id) IN ( (1, 5), . . . );
```

This sounds like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use an [EXISTS](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-exists/) clause.

I've had this need often in my production. You don't want one list vs another list separately, you want to match a set of specific *tuples*. In this example, I create a temp table, and populate it manually. You may pull the specific cust_id, order_type_id combo from elsewhere in the DB or pass them to a stored procedure or whatever.

You can also accomplish the same thing with an INNER JOIN to the table containing your filter set.

[Example Fiddle Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d4f079cabfb4d0e7667091a1dff3aed7). You specified both MySQL and Postgresql, so I just guessed. The principle will be the same in any RDMS.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(customer_id int
, order_type_id int
, order_date date);

INSERT INTO MyTable (customer_id,order_type_id,order_date)
VALUES
  (1,3,'2020-11-20')
, (1,3,'2020-11-01')
, (1,4,'2020-11-30')
, (1,5,'2020-11-25')
, (1,5,'2020-11-01')
, (1,5,'2020-11-25')

, (2,6,'2020-11-01')
, (2,6,'2020-11-25')
, (2,6,'2020-11-30')
, (2,7,'2020-11-25')
, (2,7,'2020-11-25')
, (2,8,'2020-11-01')
, (2,8,'2020-11-25');

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE CustOrd (customer_id int,order_type_id int);

INSERT INTO CustOrd (customer_id,order_type_id)
VALUES
(1,3)
,(1,5)
,(2,7)
,(2,8);


SELECT
customer_id,
order_type_id,
order_date
FROM MyTable t
WHERE order_date > '2020-11-15'
AND EXISTS (SELECT null 
            FROM CustOrd co 
            WHERE t.customer_id = co.customer_id 
            AND t.order_type_id = co.order_type_id);
```